# WinAPI: GetTokenInformation() with TokenElevationType - What do the enumerators actually mean?

Tags: winapi

Using `GetTokenInformation()` with `TokenElevationType` returns the following enumerators:

```
typedef enum _TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE {
  TokenElevationTypeDefault,
  TokenElevationTypeFull,
  TokenElevationTypeLimited
} TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE, *PTOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE;
```

But what do they actually mean?

```
TokenElevationTypeDefault
The token does not have a linked token.
TokenElevationTypeFull
The token is an elevated token.
TokenElevationTypeLimited
The token is a limited token.
```

Doesn't mean anything to me.  I can tell you `TokenElevationTypeDefault` and `TokenElevationTypeFull` seem to be what I consider "elevated" but, have no clue on how it can be elevated but in a Limited mode?

TIA!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_elevation_type

Comment: To make it short: default is when you are a standard user (or an administrator without UAC on https://candritzky.wordpress.com/tag/uac/) so you don't have two access tokens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works#sign-in-process). Limited is when you have two tokens and you are using the "standard access token". Full is when you have two tokens and you are using the "administrator access token".

Comment: @SimonMourier Ok, one follow up, does `TokenElevation` (binary result) remove the need to use `TokenElevationType`?   Logically, by name it seems the "Type" would be after checking `TokenElevation`, but in the enumerator `TokenElevation` listed *after* the `TokenElevationType` so maybe it came later?

Comment: It's the other way, you should first check the type and then, if it's TokenElevationTypeDefault, you use TokenElevation's TokenIsElevated to finally determine if the token is elevated

Comment: @SimonMourier Might be an answer sir.

Comment: @SimonMourier That makes sense.  I don't think many know that because most of these samples do things like check if UAC is enabled, etc..  when doing it this way seems more straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check official documentation here for context: [How User Account Control works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works#sign-in-process)

> By default, both standard and administrator users access resources and
> execute apps in the security context of a standard user. When a user
> signs in, the system creates an access token for that user. The access
> token contains information about the level of access that the user is
> granted [...]
>
> When an administrator logs on, two separate access tokens are created
> for the user: a *standard user access token* and an *administrator access
> token*.

So the meaning of `TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE` enum values is this:

`TokenElevationTypeDefault`: when you are a standard user (or in special cases, like an administrator without UAC on (check this link for example https://candritzky.wordpress.com/tag/uac/) so you don't have two access tokens. In this case, you can use [GetTokenInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation)'s `TokenElevation` class and [TOKEN_ELEVATION's TokenIsElevated member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_elevation) to determine if the token has elevated privileges.

`TokenElevationTypeFull`: when you have two tokens and you are using the elevated *administrator access token*.

`TokenElevationTypeLimited`: when you have two tokens and you are using the *standard user access token*.